# Why is $f \in C^{\infty}(U)$ when working with this basis of $T_pM$

Tags: differential-geometry

In Lee's Introduction to smooth manifolds page $60$ he writes:

> First, suppose that $M$ is a smooth manifold and let $(U,\varphi)$ be
> a smooth coordinate chart on $M$. Then $\varphi$ is, in particular, a
> diffeomorphism from $U$ to an open subset $\widehat{U} \subseteq
>  \mathbb{R}^n$. Combining propositions $3.9$ and $3.6(d)$ we see that
> $d\varphi_p:T_pM \to T_{\varphi(p)} \mathbb{R}^n$ is an isomorphism.

He then mentions the derivations $\left.\frac{\partial}{\partial x^1}\right\vert_{\varphi(p)},...,\left.\frac{\partial}{\partial x^n}\right\vert_{\varphi(p)}$ that are a basis for $T_{\varphi(p)}\mathbb{R}^n$. So the preimages of these under $d\varphi_p$ are a basis of $T_pM$ when we identify $T_pM \cong T_pU$ using the isomorphism $d \iota_p$, where $\iota: U \to M$ is the inclusion and similarly $T_{\varphi(p)}U \cong T_{\varphi(p)}\mathbb{R}^n$ and abuse notation by writing $d \varphi_p$ instead of the composition of these functions. The symbols $\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}\vert_p$ are then defined by $$\left.\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}\right\vert_p=(d\varphi_p)^{-1}\left(\left.\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}\right\vert_{\varphi(p)}\right)=d(\varphi^{-1})_{\varphi(p)}\left(\left.\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}\right\vert_{\varphi(p)}\right)$$ where again $\varphi$ is used to denote the composition of $\varphi$ with the inclusions. However, then he says

> Unwinding the definitions, we see that $\partial/\partial x^i \vert_p$
> acts on a function $f \in C^{\infty}(U)$ by
> $$\left.\frac{\partial}{\partial
> x^i}\right\vert_{p}f=\left.\frac{\partial}{\partial
> x^i}\right\vert_{\varphi(p)}(f \circ \varphi^{-1})$$

$(1)$ I wondered why the first centered equation holds. $(d\varphi_p)^{-1}$ should mean $(d\widehat{\iota}_{\varphi(p)} \circ d\varphi_p \circ (d \iota_p)^{-1})^{-1}$ so does $d(\varphi_p)^{-1}$ mean $(d\widehat{\iota}_{\varphi(p)})^{-1} \circ d(\varphi_p)^{-1} \circ d\iota_p$ where $\widehat{\iota}: \varphi(U) \to \mathbb{R}^n$ and $\iota:U \to M$?

$(2)$ Why is $f \in C^{\infty}(U)$ and not in $C^{\infty}(M)$? We identified in such a way that the preimages are supposed to be a basis for $T_pM$, thus being derivations $C^{\infty}(M) \to \mathbb{R}$. Is there anotoher identification used here implicitly? If so, why?

Comment: when $f\in C^\infty(M)$, then by restriction, $f\in C^\infty(U)$ as well. But the $\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}$ are only definend on $U$.

Comment: @Thomas Why are they only defined on $U$? $d\varphi_p$ is defined on $T_pM$.

Comment: ok, more precisely, they are only defined on the restriction of the tangent bundle to $U$, which is the union of the $T_pM$ with $p$ ranging over $U$. As for the why: the chart $\varphi$ is only defined on $U$.

Comment: @Thomas I think my mistake lies around the first centered equation, where I write that $\varphi$ is supposed to mean $\varphi$ composed with the inclusions, so a function $M \to \mathbb{R}^n$. But this doesnt make any sense since the inclusions are not bijective in general. However, I then don't see why the inversion commutes with the differential. $(d\varphi_p)^{-1}$ should mean $(d \iota \circ d \varphi \circ (d\iota)_p)^{-1}$, if I am not mistaken. And this is a function $T_pM \to T_{\varphi(p)}\mathbb{R}^n$ as written in the first quote in the post.

Comment: Yes. On $T_pM $ with $\mathbf{ p\in U}$. Again, $\varphi$ is only defined on $U$. You wrote that down yourself: "$\varphi$ is, in particular, a diffeomorphism from $U$ to ..."

Comment: @Thomas Yes, I know that $\varphi$ is defined on $U$, but what does that have to do with $f$ being in $C^{\infty}(U)$? If the derviations $\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}\vert_p$ are a basis for $T_pM$, then each of these acts on functions $C^{\infty}(M) \to \mathbb{R}$, since that is how $T_pM$ is defined. I don't see what I am overlooking.

Comment: Lee is choosing $f$ to be a smooth function with domain $U$. He could have chosen $f$ to be a function with domain $M$ but using one with domain $U$ works just as well.

Comment: $\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}\big\vert_p = d\varphi_p^{-1}\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}\big\vert_{\varphi(p)}\right)$ is a basis for $T_pU$, where $\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}\big\vert_{\varphi(p)}$ is a basis for $T_{\varphi(p)}\hat{U}$. If $\iota: U \to M$ is inclusion, then $d\iota_p: T_pU \to T_pM$ is an iso. Also if $\hat{\iota}: \hat{U} \to \mathbb{R}^n$, then $d\hat{\iota}_{\varphi(p)}: T_{\varphi(p)}\hat{U} \to T_{\varphi(p)}\mathbb{R}^n$ is an iso. So $d\iota_p \circ d\varphi_p^{-1} \circ d\hat{\iota}_{\varphi(p)}^{-1}$ is an iso from $T_{\varphi(p)}\mathbb{R}^n$ to $T_pM$.

Comment: So regarding question (1) you're right, if you want to be completely explicit, the isomorphism $T_{\varphi(p)}\mathbb{R}^n \to T_pM$ is a composition of $d\varphi_p^{-1}$ with differentials of inclusion maps. We usually identify $\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}\big\vert_p$ viewed as an element of $T_pM$ with $\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}\big\vert_p$ viewed as an element of $T_pU$ (even though they are actually related by the isomorphism $d\iota_p$).

Answer (score 4):

What's going on here is that I'm making use of the identification between $T_pU$ and $T_pM$ given by Proposition 3.9, as explained at the bottom of page 56 and the top of page 57.

Comment: Thanks. So when writing out the compositions explicitly as I did in $(1)$, you pretty much leave out the composition with $(d\iota_p)^{-1}$, right? However, strictly speaking, the $\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}\vert_p$ should then be a basis of $T_pU$ and are only a basis of $T_pM$ when using the identification with $(d\iota_p)^{-1}$ as well, shouldnt they? In particular, the derivations of proposition 3.15 are composed with $(d\iota_p)^{-1}$. I hope i got this right. Again, thanks.

Comment: @user3118: Yes. This is analogous to the way we use a coordinate chart $(U,\varphi)$ to identify points in $U$ with their images in Euclidean space (see the bottom of page 15). This kind of identification happens all the time in mathematics -- for example, complex numbers are commonly _defined_ as ordered pairs of real numbers with a certain multiplication operation. Once that's done, there's a canonical embedding of $\mathbb R$ into $\mathbb C$ given by $x \mapsto (x,0)$. But we usually just identify elements of $\mathbb R$ with their images in $\mathbb C$, and don't mention the embedding.

Comment: I see, I know of this abuse of notation, I just felt like there was a lot going on here so I wanted to make sure I got it right. By the way, are identifications of isomorphic structures always ok to do or does one need more information to do it? It surely makes notation more compact. On page 58, the text you mentioned, you are saying it is an harmless identification. Are there identifications that are "harmful"?

Comment: And just to be sure, you could have also used $f \in C^{\infty}(M)$ equally well here, couldn't you? One would just compose with the differential I mentioned and then one can use elements of $T_pM$.

Comment: @user3118: Yes, in principle you could use $f\in C^\infty(M)$ and apply the partial derivative operator to the composition $\widehat f = f\circ \phi^{-1}$.

Comment: @user3118: You also asked, "are identifications of isomorphic structures always ok to do or does one need more information to do it?" No, they're not always OK to do. Basically if there's a _canonical_ isomorphism (i.e., one that's not dependent on any arbitrary choices), then it's usually fine to make an identification. Or if a particular choice has been made and is understood in the present context (as is the case when working with a specific coordinate chart), then it's also OK as long as you remember that the identification depends on that choice.

Comment: But, for example, if you're just talking about a specific tangent space $T_pM$ in the absence of any chosen coordinate chart, it's not OK to identify $T_pM$ with $\mathbb R^n$ even though they're isomorphic vector spaces.

Comment: You mention a choice being made. I suppose this could be generalized to writing "let $B$ be any basis for $T_pM$ or even more generally, for a vector space $V$, and $\varphi$ be the isomorphism associated with that basis. Under this assumption it is ok to identify because I have specified an isomorphism? Basically this is what you are doing when identifying $T_pU$ with $T_pM$ isnt it? There are, in general, many isomorphisms, but you fix $d\iota_p$ and identify with this specific isomorphism, which is, in some sense, an arbitrary choice.

Comment: However, one could use, in principal, any isomorphism, say $\varphi$, so long as one made precise that one fixes $\varphi$ here, right? Thanks for your patience and explanation. By the way, you mean $\hat{f}=f \circ \varphi^{-1}$ above, right? I am curious why you were using $f \in C^{\infty}(U)$ then, because you later use a basis for $T_pM$. Is there any particular reason?